# Adding multiple DIV elements using functions with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am kind of new to JS and that is why I am asking for some help with this. I want to create multiple nested div elements like this:

```
<div>
  <div>

    <div>
    </div>

    <div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I already did create them but my mentor at work wants me to use functions so that it would make
the code more readable.

I already have tried to create multiple functions for every each element that is created, but he told me that he doesn't like it and want's me to try another way. So that is why I am asking for some help.
I already tried this (it is just a sample don't have permission to show actual code... company rules):

```
        function firstContainerCreator(){

            firstContainer= doc.createElement("div");
        }

        function innerContainerCreator(){

            innerContainer= doc.createElement("div");
        }

        function innerContainer_imgCreator(){

            innerContainer_img= doc.createElement("div");


        }

        function innerContainer_paragraphCreator(){

            innerContainer_paragraph= doc.createElement("div");

        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: should you use raw js? or can you use frameworks like jquery? did he say what exactly he dont like? did he mean really functions or objects in js?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a DIV then append children to it to get a nested structure:

```
// create the outer div
var parentDiv = document.createElement("div");

// create the inner divs
var childDiv1 = document.createElement("div");
var childDiv2 = document.createElement("div");

// now append the child divs to the parent
parentDiv.appendChild(childDiv1);
parentDiv.appendChild(childDiv2);
```

fiddle for working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Nwc3s/9/

Answer (score 0):

You have created your divs via `document.createElement("div")` (`document`, not `doc`), but you need to [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.appendChild) them onto their parent nodes.  I would recommend against attempting to wrap the creation of these into functions like you had originally, until you have a good understanding of how they are created and nested.

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/YBLDz/)...

```
// The outer div:
var outer_container = document.createElement("div");
// Append it onto the body
document.body.appendChild(outer_container);

// Main inner div
var main_inner = document.createElement("div");
// Append to outer
outer_container.appendChild(main_inner);

// First innermost div
var first_inner = document.createElement("div");
// Second innermost div
var second_inner = document.createElement("div");
// append to main inner div
main_inner.appendChild(first_inner);
main_inner.appendChild(second_inner);

// etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so what's the issue? You have created the elements, now append them by Javascript's native `appendChild` method:

```
parent = document.getElementById("parentdiv");
parent.appendChild(firstContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function createDivNode(parentNode){
    // in case no parent div use <body> as parent
    if (!parentNode) var parentNode = document.body;
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    parentNode.appendChild( el );
    return el;
}

var outer = createDivNode();
var inner1 = createDivNode(outer);
var inner2 = createDivNode(outer);
```

output:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9FMPv/9/

Answer (score 0):

Below is a function that will create a parent container, 3 child divs, and a grandchild div for each of the child divs.

```
var createDivs = (function() {
  var parent = document.createElement('div'),
    children = 3,
    // change this number to reflect how many child divs you need
    gchildren = 3,
    // same with this
    i = 0;
  document.body.appendChild(parent);
  this.appendGChild = function(child) {
    console.log(child);
    var gchild = document.createElement('div'),
        i = 0;
    for (i = gchildren; i--;) {
        child.appendChild(gchild);
    }
  }
  for (i = children; i--;) {
    var child = document.createElement('div');
    parent.appendChild(child);
    appendGChild(child);
  }

})();​
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cNJtX/) that illustrates this.